# Print non-printable characters as fullstop in Java

Tags: java, hex, ascii

I have a Hex string that needs to be converted to ASCII and be printed. While debugging, I can see the correct values but when I try to print the ASCII, it ignores it and moves to the next. Is there a way I can replace all the non-printable characters as dot(.). Here is my snippet:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
byte[] out = toByteArray("0000005401F40000D9E3C60500000000002000000000000000D7C8F10000000000000000000000004040404040404040D9E3C600E9C7C9F0F0F0F1F1E5D9C1D1C1D54040F0F0F14BF0F0F14BF0F0F14BF0F0F100"); // Input Hex String
System.out.println("ASCII: " + out); // Prints [B@15db9742
String hex = toHexString(out);
System.out.println("Hex: " + hex); // Prints the hex - 00000054 exactly

public static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

Comment: System.out.println("ASCII: " + Arrays.toString(out));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
public class Main {

    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] out = toByteArray("0000005401F40000D9E3C60500000000002000000000000000D7C8F10000000000000000000000004040404040404040D9E3C600E9C7C9F0F0F0F1F1E5D9C1D1C1D54040F0F0F14BF0F0F14BF0F0F14BF0F0F100"); // Input Hex String
        System.out.println("ASCII: " + Arrays.toString(out)); 
        String hex = toHexString(out);
        System.out.println("Hex: " + hex); // Prints the hex - 00000054 exactly


    }
    public static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

Examples of replacing :

```
  //non-ASCII
String yourstring = Arrays.toString(out).replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", ".");


  //non-printable characters
String yourstring = Arrays.toString(out).replaceAll("\\p{C}", ".");
```

Comment: This solved part of my problem, but the main problem is like I need to replace the non-printable characters with a "dot".

Comment: To do this you need a regular expression , in **replaceall** string method